# Saving large file exceeds frameLimit

Tags: apache-spark, word2vec

I try to save a large text file of a approx. 5GB

```
sc.parallelize(cfile.toString()
  .split("\n"), 1)
  .saveAsTextFile(new Path(path+".cs", "data").toUri.toString)
```

but I keep getting

```
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
...
org.apache.spark.shuffle.MetadataFetchFailedException: Missing an output location for shuffle 6
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:542)
    at org.apache.spark.MapOutputTracker$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$MapOutputTracker$$convertMapStatuses$2.apply(MapOutputTracker.scala:538)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
```

I'm stuck here for ages now. Can anybody help me here and explain how I can save `cfile` as a textfile?

---

Standalone/Local/Yarn cluster?

- Yarn cluster

Memory/Cores settings?

- 1,8 TB
- 285 Cores

Number of Partitions?

- I am currently setting the number of partitions to `1`:

The concerned lines of code for setting the number of partitions:

```scala
val model = word2vec
  .setMinCount(minCount.asInstanceOf[Int])
  .setVectorSize(arguments.getVectorSize)
  .setWindowSize(arguments.getContextWindowSize)
  .setNumPartitions(numW2vPartitions)
  .setLearningRate(learningRate)
  .setNumIterations(arguments.getNumIterations)
  .fit(wordSequence)
```

*spark-submit* arguments:

```
spark-submit --master yarn 
             --deploy-mode cluster 
             --driver-memory 20G 
             --num-executors 5 
             --executor-cores 8 
             --driver-java-options "-Dspark.akka.frameSize=2000" 
             --executor-memory 20G --class
```

Answer (score 0):

Standalone/Local/Yarn cluster?
Memory/Cores settings?
Number of Partitions?

Your error probably symptom that one of the workers are gone(OOM killer might have killed it or it got some OOM error)

I'm not sure why are you doing this: cfile.toString().split("\n") - from this I understand that you hold all 5GB content in memory and try to parallelize it ?  Clearly it's not optimal.
Another problem that could be relevant - if you driver can hold all 5GB in memory somehow, but still all network layers between driver-workers won't like this amount of data - so my advice to split it into partitions.

instead you can read file with sc.textFile(..) and then save it into your new path. You also can control number of partitions(pieces) of your text file with sc.textFile(..).repartition(100).

Comment: Actually I am trying to save a word vector model there is a [spark version](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/Word2Vec.scala#L625) of a `save()` method that is simply not working and I have no idea why. I contacted the user group but got no answer since then. This is why I thought I could just simply save my model as a CSV file and circumvent that seemingly broken implementation. I will update my question with your requested information.

Comment: The driver program has actually 20GB of RAM, it's the same for each of the 8 workers I am using currently.

Comment: So how did you convert model to cfile? I mean lets assume model is some kind of rdd and you want to save it as text, so you can tranform this rdd to be rdd of strings in parallel(without bringing it all to driver as you probably do) and then save it to hdfs also in parrallel

Comment: Well.. spark returns a `Map[String, Array[Float]]` which is a map from a word to its word vector. `Word2Vec#SaveLoadV1_0#save()` is supposed to handle that for me but it's either broken of I simply don't understand what I have to do to make this work. Since it doesn't, I am just iterating the map and convert all `(word, word-vector)` pairs to a C line. That one is in the end a `Seq[String]` which I would like to store in *one* large file. The reason is because I am going to use that model file in another library since spark w2v has currently no doc2vec implementation.

Comment: I have to admit that I am rather new to Spark (same for Scala) which is my might simply lack of some basic understanding or knowledge. Still I don't understand why everything is working fine unless I try to save that model that took like 24 hours to train ..

Comment: ok, now I understand your case a bit better. 2 thoughts: Have you tried to save this map to local file instead of doing this parallilizing thing? I mean  -  you already have answer at driver of form of Map[String, Array[Float]], so go over it and save it into local file(on driver) or in hdfs(don't use spark for this). Second thought: can you check that your yarn workers are not failing? It might happen that despite that you see error while writing the output the real problem is in computation itself and it fails at writing time just because spark jobs are lazy evaluated.